# How to show js message from html action

Tags: javascript, html, action

I have this form in html

```
<form class="form-horiz" role="form" action="" >
    <div class="form-group-1" style="margin-left:5px">
      <div class="col-sm-10">          
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="adsend" placeholder="Enter your ad"  >
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group-1">        
      <div class="col-sm-offset">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="send" id="send" >Send</button>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="classify">Classify</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

What I need to do is: The user will write something in text and after click on *classify button* js message will appear to the user with some results, is it possible to do something in `action=""` or there is another way to do it?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I tried but still stuck. I'm working on classifier, if user type "Lionel Messi" and click classify button, js message said: (Sports)

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I tried to replace it with js form but still not getting the text from input. I tried what this link said http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can use event listeners for button clicks if you'd like instead of form actions. Check out [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) documentation, hopefully it'll help! I'd suggest something like this:

```
<form class="form-horiz" role="form" action="" >
    <div class="form-group-1" style="margin-left:5px">
      <div class="col-sm-10">          
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="adsend" placeholder="Enter your ad"  >
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group-1">        
      <div class="col-sm-offset">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="send" id="send" >Send</button>
         <button id="classify" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="classify">Classify</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

and then have this in some js file

```
document.getElementById("classify").addEventListener("click", function () {
  // do some js stuff here
});
```

EDIT:
Another alternative would be to use an `onclick` attribute, which is also documented in the link I posted before, but this is a little antiquated, and your function has to be named in the global scope and it's not really a good idea in general. I'd go with an event listener!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to have jQuery added into your Application. It makes your life easier in your construction.

```
Check this https://jsfiddle.net/dqwLv8q7/
```

I added id in your button and made it preventDefault() as it fire us submit action of your form as you set it "type=submit". So your "classify" click button now just shows Alert message with value of your "adsend" ID input value. You can consider to use another tag and replace it with message to your user.

Comment: There really isn't any reason to use jquery with this

Comment: I am aware of fact that you can do this with plain js, however jQuery makes it easier and predictable. And there is no reason not to use jQuery my friend.

Comment: It really doesn't at all, you're loading a whole library to replace `document.querySelector` or `document.getElementById` with `$(`. Just make a keyboard snippet if you really don't want to type it that badly.